# Different variable lengths when looping over a string vector which corresponds to data frame columns

Tags: r, string, for-loop, lme4

I am new in writing loops and I have some difficulties there. I already looked through other questions, but didn't find the answer to my specific problem.

So lets just create a random dataset, give column names and set the variables as character:

```
d<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:9,197,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(d)<-c("variable1","variable2","trait1","trait2")
d$variable1<-as.character(d$variable1)
d$variable2<-as.character(d$variable2)
```

Now I define my vector over which I want to loop. It correspons to trait 1 and trait 2:

```
trt.nm <- names(d[c(3,4)])
```

Now I want to apply the following model for trait 1 and trait 2 (which should now be as column names in trt.nm) in a loop:

```
library(lme4)
for(trait in trt.nm)
{
  lmer (trait ~ 1 + variable1 + (1|variable2) ,data=d)
}
```

Now I get the error that variable lengths differ. How could this be explained?

If I apply the model without loop for each trait, I get a result, so the problem has to be somewhere in the loop, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trait` is a string, so you'll  have to convert it to a formula to work; see http://www.cookbook-r.com/Formulas/Creating_a_formula_from_a_string/ for more info.

Try this (you'll have to add a print statement or save the result to actually see what it does, but this will run without errors):

```
for(trait in trt.nm) {
  lmer(as.formula(paste(trait, " ~ 1 + variable1 + (1|variable2)")), data = d)
}
```

Another suggestion would be to use a list and `lapply` or `purrr::map` instead. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful for the sample code. The problem with my actual code is that I use asreml (just thought because it's not open source I would not poste it) and there it's slightly different:  poinmodel <- asreml(fixed= trait ~ 1 +plantcode,
                               random= ~ source + block + pgrgroup+source:pgrgroup,
                               family= asreml.gaussian(),
                               data = poin)                                                                             The paste function seems not to work if trait comes after the fixed effect.

Comment: You just need to create a string that says ```"fixed= desired_trait_name ~ 1 +plantcode"```, then use ```as.formula``` again. Aka ```paste("fixed = ", trait, "~ 1 + plantcode")```.

Comment: as always, `reformulate()` might be slightly cleaner.